# Make install starts to compile. Can I abort?

Tags: compilation, makefile, installation, abort

I'm trying to install llvm on an arm and it does take a lot of time. (I know crosscompiling would be faster, but i didn't get it to work yet)
I'm accessing the system through the serial port.

I ran the configure script and started "sudo make ENABLE_OPTIMIZED=1 -j$(nproc)" to compile.
Since I knew it would take forever I turned off the pc in the meantime.
Foolishly I didn't print the output to a file, so I have no information about whether everything worked or not.
When I came back a day later, I just assumed everything is fine and started "make install".

Now I see that the system is again compiling tons of files which usually are compiled at "make".

I'm a beginner with Linux, so I thought at the make install stage no compilation is done anymore.
Also the "tutorials" like [Why always ./configure; make; make install; as 3 separate steps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10961439/why-always-configure-make-make-install-as-3-seperate-steps) don't mention compiling at "make install".

So the actual questions:

- Is there usually also compiling involved in the make install stage or is it almost certain that make failed at some point and make install is trying to fix that?
- Is it a very bad idea to terminate the make install and restart the dual-core mode of make "make ENABLE_OPTIMIZED=1 -j$(nproc) >> out.txt" before rerunning make install? 
  Or do I have to wait for "make install" to finish, because it already started to install stuff and I shouldn't mess around with it?

I appreciate your suggestions!!

Comment: hey has compilation finished yet? if not you can probably abort it now and start again without any issue

Comment: It hadn't finished, I aborted it.

It seems as the ARM was out of memory during compilation. This is why it started to compile again when i ran "make install". (I still assume there usually is no compilation done at make install)

I created a swap file as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19761226/how-to-compile-ruby-with-rvm-on-a-low-memory-system)
and restarted make. Now it seems to work, but I'll carefully check the output now and hope there is no damage in the files ;-)

Comment: make install will run compilation if needed, because of how make works - it needs to complete the dependencies of make install (i.e. make) for make install itself to run, which in your case involve compilation.