# OpenSSL compile error when installing Ruby 1.8.7 using RVM

Tags: ruby, linux, centos, rvm

Using RVM to install Ruby 1.8.7, this error occurs:

```
Error running '__rvm_make -j4',
showing last 15 lines of /home/XXXX/.rvm/log/1446528129_ruby-1.8.7-p374/make.log
                 from ossl_ssl_session.c:5:
openssl_missing.h:95:5: error: conflicting types for ‘EVP_CIPHER_CTX_copy’
 int EVP_CIPHER_CTX_copy(EVP_CIPHER_CTX *out, EVP_CIPHER_CTX *in);
     ^
In file included from /usr/local/include/openssl/x509.h:73:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/openssl/x509v3.h:62,
                 from ossl.h:58,
                 from ossl_ssl_session.c:5:
/usr/local/include/openssl/evp.h:459:5: note: previous declaration of ‘EVP_CIPHER_CTX_copy’ was here
 int EVP_CIPHER_CTX_copy(EVP_CIPHER_CTX *out, const EVP_CIPHER_CTX *in);
     ^
make[1]: *** [ossl_ssl_session.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/var/groupon/home/XXXXX/.rvm/src/ruby-1.8.7-p374/ext/openssl'
make: *** [all] Error 1
++ return 2
There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.
```

I tried the method mentioned in "[How to compile ruby with RVM on a low memory system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19761226/how-to-compile-ruby-with-rvm-on-a-low-memory-system)" but I still have the same problem.

#### update

problem solved:

```
rvm pkg install openssl
```

Comment: Why do you want to install ruby 1.8.7?

Comment: Ruby 1.8.7 was removed from support years ago. Why do you want to install it? You will be creating a maintenance problem for yourself.

Comment: @KMRakibulIslam A history problem. My company didn't update the ruby version